# how to install python-dev with no root?

Tags: python-2.7, debian, apt

I am trying to install YouCompleteMe, the installation guide says I need "python-dev"

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

My question is how do I install this with out root access on Debian.

How can I check if I have python-dev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to check the installation status, you can use

```
 dpkg-query -l python-dev
```

the first row will give you the installation status (`ii` means (currently) `installed` and (to-be) `installed`)

you cannot *install* a package without root-access (that's the point of root-access: having the priviliges to modify the system components).
However, you can download the `.deb` file and *extract* it locally:

```
wget http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python-dev_2.7.9-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -x python-dev_2.7.9-1_amd64.deb .
```

(this will download python-dev and extract it into your current directory)

Comment: Should we add the extracted path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: no. the `python-dev` package doesn't provide any shared libraries.

Comment: So, where to put the extracted files? Any variable has to set?

Comment: @skepticscript: To be honest, I don't remember exactly. I think the program needed some other libraries and I finally list all things to the admin to install them!

Answer (score 0):

you can download the  source code at [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/); the c/c++ header files (which are in the debian package python-dev) are included in there.

Comment: "which are in the debian package python-dev" could you be more specific please? I am not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: python-dev provides the header files and static libraries you need in order to compile python. but everything that is in there can be downloaded directly from python as well. these are mostly `*.h` files.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure I follow (sorry I am new to this) I did the following: downloaded python source, it looks like it has *.h files in the Include folder. then I installed python using ./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install. Does this mean I have python-dev? do I no longer need to try and run "sudo apt-get install python-dev"

Answer (score 0):

To check if you have python-dev installed issue

```
dpkg -l | grep python-dev
```

If it is not installed you don't have root you will need to download the sourcecode for the version of Python you are working with from http://python.org the files that are included in the python-dev package should be under the include/ direcotory of the tarball I believe.